# Add another item to a List<>

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to add another item to an existing `List<>` in my Android application. My `List<>` is initialised here:

```
List<ListsRecyclerViewList> list = new Arrays.asList(newListsRecyclerViewList("item", "item"));
```

The `ListsRecyclerViewList` class looks like this:

```
public String name;
public String date;

public ListsRecyclerViewList(String name, String date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return name;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

Is there any way to add another item to the `List<>`? Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can just wrap it in `new ArrayList<ListsRecyclerViewList>(Arrays.asList(...))` also...

Comment: did you, a/ try? b/ read the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` returned from using `Arrays.asList(...)` cannot have its size modified as explained in its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the
>   List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but
>   the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying
>   array.

Do this instead:

```
List<ListsRecyclerViewList> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(newListsRecyclerViewList("item", "item"));
```

and then sometime later:

```
list.add(newListsRecyclerViewList("anotherItem", "anotherItem"));
```